# XIB to Storyboard with IB Action not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to link a supporting pages XIB back to a storyboard view (ViewController), the main page. I just get a black screen. In the .h file (supporting page) I have:

```
-(IBAction)gotoViewController;
```

In the .m file I have:

```
 -(IBAction)gotoViewController
{
    ViewController *PT = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:PT animated:YES];
}
```

I did import the ViewController into the .m file, but when the button is pressed, it goes to a black screen. I am positive that it is linked correctly. Can XIB files be linked to a storyboard?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you checked to see that you are getting a non-nil value for *PT once you've gone through the method with the debugger?  It's a little hard to figure out the source of your issue looking at the method only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but calling the `initwithNibName:bundle:` method with `nil` as argument twice might be a wrong way to initialize your view controller. Try this:

```
ViewController *PT = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

I assume your xib has the same name as the class (`ViewController`)?

Also make sure that, in the xib, all the outlets are properly linked up. I've merged projects from the storyboard back to xibs aswell and you might need to set the `view` property of your `UIViewController`, and you should probably set the class of your File's Owner to the correct class.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For a view controller defined in a storyboard, you need to instantiate your view controller with the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method of your `UIStoryboard` instance.